# Symfony2 Shared Host bad Performance maybe cache?

Tags: php, performance, symfony, caching, shared-hosting

I use the default config of Symfony2 app.php

```
> <?php
> 
> use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader; use
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
> 
> $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
> 
> // Enable APC for autoloading to improve performance. // You should
> change the ApcClassLoader first argument to a unique prefix // in
> order to prevent cache key conflicts with other applications // also
> using APC. /* $apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__),
> $loader); $loader->unregister(); $apcLoader->register(true);
> */
> 
> require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php'; //require_once
> __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';
> 
> $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false); $kernel->loadClassCache();
> //$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
> 
> // When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front
> controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
> //Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride(); $request =
> Request::createFromGlobals(); $response = $kernel->handle($request);
> $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);`
```

Now to my issue:

I have local apache who render some templates in Symfony 2 project in 200ms-250ms in prod.
There is no database in the background.
Now my issue is that if i request same page in webhost i have request time from 1sec to 8sec.

I just have some layout twigs and then the content partials in.

I dont know why i got so high requests times
here is a reques header example:

```
General: Request URL:http://####/## 
Request Method:GET 
Status Code:200 OK 
Remote Address:####

Response Headers: view source 
Cache-Control:no-cache 
Connection:Keep-Alive 
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date:Sat, 18 Jun 2016 14:41:39 GMT 
Keep-Alive:timeout=2, max=98 
Server:Apache 
Transfer-Encoding:chunked X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.6
```

Anyone have a idea to get some information to debug or maybe someone know the reason of the bad performance on webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help some modifications to the server like described here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/performance.html

Especially

```
; php.ini
realpath_cache_size=4096K
realpath_cache_ttl=600
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: It depends.

Performance is always a topic where it is hard to say what's the problem when you donn't know the code and environment. **You have to measure it.**

With Symfony it's easy to get a simple measurement by using the [Profiler Toolbar](https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html).
Just install and enable it on your application. You will see the toolbar at the bottom of the page. On the performance tab you get a pretty nice overview on what time is spent for rendering, controllers etc. 
Based on this informations you can optimize your code or environment.

[image: Profiler - Image from the Symfony Blog]

If you need more insight about performance you can try [xhProf](http://php.net/manual/de/book.xhprof.php), [xDebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) or commercial tools like [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io/) or [Tideways](https://tideways.com/).